# Stripping out inactive/unused source files

Tags: java, tomcat, ant, weblogic-10.x

I'm working on a project which is requiring a lot of refactoring. So there have been a lot of classes that are completely unused. Is there a way from within ant (java compile options) to strip out these unused sources while building? Or is there a way to configure Weblogic/Tomcat not to deploy those files?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610163/does-javac-removes-methods-that-are-not-referenced-in-the-code and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061124/java-proguard-remove-shrink-unused-classes

Answer (score 1):

[proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) can "shake the tree" and remove any unused classes from your jar file. Unfortunately it looks like the website is down currently.